# How to execute rawSql in Yesod

Tags: yesod

I am new to Yesod and I am having trouble executing simple rawSql statement in Scaffolded site.

```
module Handler.RawSQL where

import Import

getRawSQLR :: Handler Html
getRawSQLR = do
    users <- runDB $ rawSql "SELECT ident, password FROM user" []
    defaultLayout $(widgetFile "rawsql")
```

I am getting error:
    Handler/RawSQL.hs:7:22: Not in scope: ‘rawSql’

What am I doing wrong and how do I show "users" in hamlet template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just need to import the `rawSql` function:

```
import Database.Persist.Sql (rawSql)
```

Comment: Than you. This was already in "import Import" but obviously I had to restart stack (Ctrl+D and then again: stack exec -- yesod devel).

Comment: Cool, enjoy using Yesod @ladek!